# What defines a halachik tzadik?

Tags: halacha, tzaddikim

Is there a halachik definition of a tzadik?

There is the rambam's definition in hilchos teshuva 3:1 That it's someone who is 51% mitzvos. But according to this definition basically everyone is a tzadik, and it's definitely not how people use the term.

One application would be
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90988/6788

Comment: have you ever learned tanya. the beginning of tanya answers this very question

Comment: Are you asking about how the term is used by people, or what the Halachic definition is?  You gave the Halachic definition from the Rambam!

Comment: @Laser123  I haven't learned Tanya, and I'd like to see it!  Please, write it out as an answer.

Comment: @Laser123 tanya is not a halachik definition as far as I understand

Comment: One who does good and shuns evil.

Comment: @mroll Why would you say that? Is quantifying someone as a tzaddik halachic anyway?

Comment: @Laser123 Tanya's opinion is not mainstream; it's one of the distinguishing features of our chassidus

Comment: @mroll You are correct. The discussion in the beginning of Tanya is not a halachic definition. It is setting the foundation for a discussion of hashkafa.

Comment: @SAH The discussion in Tanya is mainstream but isn’t limited to the halachic definition, like the Alter Rebbe himself clarifies on 5b of the 1st chapter in Tanya. The 51% concept only applies to the subject of reward and punishment.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thanks. But what do you mean by your last sentence? Is it suggesting that a 51%-tzadik is rewarded as a tzadik gamur? !

Comment: @SAH You’re welcome. Not exactly, but it gets more complicated with reflection. Like Ramchal explains in the 1st section of Derech HaShem, those ‘closest to G-d’ AKA Tzaddikim Gamurim, are held in the highest esteem, a 2nd aspect of this judgement is because those with less than 51% merit are boosted by those with more merit. That is also said by Rambam & hinges on the unique Jewish state of ‘Tzibbur’, (כל ישראל ערבים זה בזה). In the last analysis, the goal is to minimize Din. Like Navi says, an exceedingly small number don’t make it including all non-Jews. And that is through all time.

Comment: It might be the 2nd section of Derech HaShem. It’s the part talking about the future perfected community. A point worth noting about these Tzaddikim Gamurim is that part of what makes them what they are is that they are completely given over, meaning devoted, to the whole. For an example, see the discussion in Pesikta Rabbati between Ephraim, Moshiach Tzidki and G-d, when Moshiach agrees to take on the job of redeeming the Jewish people.

Comment: @SAH The section you will find helpful from Ramchal is Section 2, part 2, paragraphs 1-9. Here's a link: https://www.sefaria.org/Derech_Hashem,_Part_Two,_On_Mankind_in_This_World?lang=bi

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thanks so much. Sefaria doesn't have English for this source so I can't read the original (yet). 1) Who is Navi? Very difficult to find out from Google. 2) Is he quite sure *all* non-Jews "don't make it," and what does "not make it" mean, exactly? What about Iyov, etc.? Is this a standard perspective or just Navi's? This is an exceedingly difficult concept for those of us who are, for whatever reason, very close to non-Jews. ... Sorry to focus on a sub-question that is not your iker, but this grabbed me. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @SAH The Ramchal book is called “The Way of G-d” in English and is available from Feldheim Publishers, I think. The translator was Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan, A”H. If you haven’t read it, you should put it on your ‘to do’ list. By “Navi”, I meant prophet. I was referring to Isaiah the Prophet. He is the one who uses that language. And it doesn’t say all non-Jews don’t make it. The opposite, only an exceedingly small number don’t make it. And that is talking about from all who have ever existed from Adam HaRishon.

Comment: @SAH See Isaiah 16:14

Comment: @SAH  The Way of G-d in Hebrew/English:  https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/087306769X/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1523468797&sr=8-1&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_QL65&keywords=the+way+of+god+kaplan&dpPl=1&dpID=51S2AA-BPeL&ref=plSrch

Comment: @SAH The Way of G-d translated into English online:   https://torah.org/series/ramchal/

Answer (score 2):

The Rokeah defines Tzaddik by the Notrikon of the middle letters צדיק, דרך ישר a person who abides by the straight path of Mitzvot, not 51% I am afraid as RAMBAM said.  (appears in Sefer Az Yashir Moshe, Page Kaf Hey, Parashat Noach)

Comment: כלל העולה כי קיום תרי"ג מצות ע"י היות יצר הרע באדם והוא מתגבר עליו- נקרא צדיק
“A rising rule, fulfilling 613 mitzvot while Yetzer Hara rises and he overcomes it, is called TZADDIK Appears in Rabbi Chayim Vital's “Shaarei Kedusha”/ Gates of holiness book Part Alef, Shaar Gimel

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Oudi and thanks for a great first answer. Please note comments are not meant to stay so please [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/91158/edit) your comment into the main text. Hope to see you around !

Comment: And yet, this too is not a halachic definition. The Rambam quoted in the question is part of the definition found in Mishnah Torah. Even there, Rambam points out there are levels of Tzaddikim. And the general concept in regard to judgement of who is righteous is to be as all inclusive as possible. The hope is that no one is excluded.